# unable to connect postgres from the docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have pgAdmin4 and postgresql installed separately on my Mac server.
and I have a Spring boot application running in docker container in local

from application, I'm trying to give `localhost:5433` in the connection string
`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/database1`. However it is not connecting.

error

```
Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

can someone please help.

Also, I noticed my `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf` and `/Library/PostgreSQL/14/data/postgresql.conf` are also not matching. do we need to have these two in sync?

Answer (score 1):

change localhost to host.docker.internal it should work i.e.

change `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/database1` into `jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5433/database1`

btw, postgresql default port is 5432 if I'm not forgetting, so may be you'll need to change the port number if you haven't explicitly set it to 5433